# How to turn the EditorFor into DATETIME picker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I want my EditorFor fields for DateFrom and DateTo to become a datetime picker (not datepicker). I successfully created it once but I lost my file. I couldn't remember if I used EditorFor or TextBoxFor for that.

Also, how can I make the full name editorfor to be read only? I tried a link from stackoverflow but the field was still editable.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Approval</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateFrom)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { @class="date", type = "datetime-local"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateFrom)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, new { @class="datepicker", type = "datetime-local"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTo)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EditorFor Or TextboxFor any will work you just need to add correct js file and initializer for datetimepicker.

You can use as

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new { @readonly = "readonly" ,@id="datepicker" })
```

**OR**

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, new { @readonly = "readonly" ,@id="datepicker" })
```

You Need three js files

1. jquery
2. jquery-ui and
3. Jquery datetimepicker addon

Also You Need 2 css file

1. jquery ui
2. Jquery datetimepicker addon

To be clear have a look on following snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
            controlType: 'select',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
       
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon@1.6.3/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon@1.6.3/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>Date and Time:
  <input type="text" readonly=true id="datepicker">
</p>
```